# Use information from custom extractor in custom outputter

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have implemented a custom extractor for NetCDF files and now I'm trying to implement a custom outputter for NetCDF files. When extracting from and outputting to NetCDF files, in the outputter I need to use some of the structural information found in the input files during extraction. Is there some way to store information when extracting that can be used in a custom outputter?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to flow the information from your extract statement as part of the rowset into your output statement if the information is not known at compile time.

Comment: I now have two extract statements. One which extracts the real input data and one that extracts some metadata about the input data. Then I do some processing of the input data and now I'm implementing a custom outputter to output the processed input data. In the custom outputter, I need the metadata and I would like to pass it into the custom outputter in some way, but I don't know how.

Comment: You can use DEPLOY RESOURCE "adlspath"; to have the file containing the metadata copied to the custom outputter's local working directory. So you can read the file content inside your outputter code.